# If NSNotificationCenter wouldn't exist, how would you implement it?

Tags: ios, nsnotifications

I was asked by this question and I actually don't know how to achieve it.

Please help.

Comment: A dictionary - `[Event:[Observer]]` ?

Comment: Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 4):

1. It's probably a singleton, meaning there is always one and only one in your app.
2. It's probably doing a "delegate" pattern, except with an array of delegates instead of only one delegate.
3. When you add an observer, the class that was added gets tossed into the array of delegates from #2.  (And when you remove an observer, it gets removed from that array.)
4. When you post a notification, the singleton in #1 loops through the delegate array (from #2) and calls the callback method associated with each delegate in it's array. (ok, technically it sends a message, but you get the idea)